# Как автоматически заполнить текстом 3 колонки?(bootstrap)

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть 3 блока в 1 ряду,нпример как тут:
[image: пример]
Это можно сделать в bootstrap создав `row`,3 колонки в нем, и накидав текст в каждую колонку(то есть самому разделить целый текст на 3 равные части и вставить в колонки). Возник вопрос, можно ли избежать возни с делением текста? то есть создать элемент,который сам будет разбивать вставленный целый текст на 3 части и заполнять блоки в колонках автоматчиески?

Comment: Средствами html/css (а судя по меткам, интересует такое решение) - нет. Скриптами - да.

Comment: @Pyramidhead конкретных предпочтений в технологиях нет. эти метки указаны постольку,поскольку в примере использовались эти технологии и я не знал,что такое можно сделать с помощью скриптов. вас не затруднит поделиться источником информации,где описан такой скрипт?(это,наверное какой-нибудь плагин Jquery?)

Comment: Я не знаю таких плагинов. Самый простой вариант - это строчек пять кода.

Comment: @Pyramidhead ну вы тролите). Кхм по сабжу - все верно. С помощью JS скрипта можно сделать разделение текста на 3 части. Алгоритм простой - находим длинну текста и делим это значение на 3. Находим целое число и пытаемся поделить текст. Там добавляем проверки что мы не разрываем слово по частям и потом получаем 3 куска текста. Которые потом распределяются в нужные куски DOM (3 строки кода). Но это "сложный вариант" и потому уже не 5 строчек кода =)

Comment: @alexoander теперь понял.постараюсь это реализовать,если получится,выложу сюда.большое спасибо за идею